# Is there a better way than friend classes here?

Tags: c++

Programming in C++ for Windows although this situation could arise anywhere. This is a simplified version of my problem to keep the question manageable so don't get too caught up on the detail :)

I have a class `class Window` which contains a windows `HWND` data item. I want to fully encapsulate that `HWND` so that the user of the class has to go through the class to perform any operations on that window, so it's stored in a private member variable. I don't want to provide any public "getter" for it as that would break the encapsulation allowing the user to bypass my class.

Now I want to create a class `class Direct3d11` to encapsulate some of the directx api. In order to create an instance of this class it requires the HWND of a window so I pass it a `Window` object in it's constructor.

```
class Direct3D11
{
public:
    Direct3D11(const Window& window);
};
```

Inside the constructor it has access to the window object, however it requires the HWND contained within in order to be able to physically create the windows objects that the Direct3D11 class will manage, but there is no way for it to obtain that information.

I could add a private getter function to get the HWND to the Window class, and then make the Direct3D11 class a friend class of Window so that it call call the function.

However this doesn't seem very elegant not least because class Window has otherwise no need to know anything at all about class Direct3D11.

Am I missing a better way to achieve this? Friend classes don't appeal, and having a public getter function doesn't much appeal either.

Comment: Seems to me like a use case for `friend` indeed.

Comment: You basically have two choices, either make the getter available to everyone (i.e. make it `public`), or make it only available to certain other people (i.e. use `friend`).  Those are the logical possibilities.  About the only other distinct approach I can think of is to have `Direct3D11` inherit from `Window`; whether or not that makes sense is up to you... ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: With all respect, that's obnoxious. I still like to think of inheritance as a form of IS-A relation (although it can't really model it accurately, but that's another story). Here, making `Direct3D11` inherit from `Window` would establish a meaningless relationship. I guess this is a natural use case for `friend`.

Comment: There are a lot of Windows APIs that require HWNDs, Direct3D is just one example. I think you should just provide a getter for the HWND, otherwise you limit the users too much.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Yes, that was kind of what I was implying... ;)

Comment: You could create an intermediate class that is the friend of Windows that accesses the HWND through a private accessor and then friend that class to Direct3D11. But, to my eye, it seems pretty pointless.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Huh, all right then ;-)

Comment: I'm trying to wrap a small part of the win32 API that I need for my application in my own more "c++ style" interface so the rest of the system can use that interface. I'd like to prevent windows specific types from escaping that wrapper. Whether this is a good idea remains to be seen :P

Comment: I just don't understand why people keep thinking that `friend` is bad and breaks encapsulation.

Comment: Friend isn't bad for that reason, friend is bad because I want to divide my my software into modules, one for windows api and one for direct 3d and this makes them depend on each other directly  when I'd rather have a hierarchy of modules. It may be unavoidable without worse problems which is why I wanted to ask for idea.

Answer (score 3):

You could create the `Direct3D11` class inside `Window`, since `Windows` owns the `HWND`.

Something along these lines:

```
class Window
{
    HWND hwnd;
    Direct3D11 d;
public:
    Window() : d(hwnd) {}
    Direct3D11& getDirect3D()
    {
       return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for every window to contain a Direct3D object. Direct3D is generally only created for one single window in an application.

Comment: Or, I suppose, offer a creation function that creates the Direct3D11 on demand, e.g. `Direct3D11* createDirect3D() { return new Direct3D11(hwnd); }`

Comment: I'm not sure I want to do that. It's given me an idea though. I could create some kind of factory class that knows how to create various objects that depend on hwnds and make *that* a friend of Window thus keeping any knowledge of my Direct3D class out of Window. Needs more thought...

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe have a function on Window called Execute. It would take in a std::function with a placeholder for HWND as a parameter. Window would then call the function with HWND as its only parameter.

This would require c++11, but the code would be similar to :

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    explicit Foo(int num) : num_(num) {}
    template<typename T>
    void execute(std::function<T> f) const { f(num_); }
    private:
    int num_;
};

struct Bar{
    void print_nums(int i,int j)
    {
        std::cout << "i:" << i << ", " << "j:" << j << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo o(42);
    Bar b;

    //the function we want to execute requires an int
    //that Foo knows about
    typedef void myFunction(int);

    // store the result of a call to std::bind
    std::function<myFunction> display_1337_first = std::bind(&Bar::print_nums, b,1337, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<myFunction> display_1337_last = std::bind(&Bar::print_nums, b, std::placeholders::_1, 1337);
    o.execute<myFunction>(display_1337_first);
    o.execute<myFunction>(display_1337_last);
    return 0; 
}

//output:
//i:1337, j:42
//i:42, j:1337
```

Comment: Since that allows anyone to get the HWND from a Window, I don't see how it's any better than simply providing a getter function. They both break the encapsulation, but this way is a lot more cumbersome to use.

Comment: I think its cleaner. You would call execute when you wanted to do something with the handle. Sure, you can copy the value back, but why would you? I think the closest analogy I can think of is that this example is a "Put"er - When the value is needed, the instance in question fills in the required information and the function call proceeds.

Comment: You really think that `win.execute([&d3d](HWND hwnd){d3d = createDirect3D(hwnd);});` is cleaner than `d3d = createDirect3D(win.getHwnd());`? In any case, it doesn't answer the question since it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: How does it break encapsulation if: (1) The class still has control over access to the value before it is used and (2) its a const method?

Comment: It breaks encapsulation because it lets the user use the HWND for any purpose, which the OP specifically said he doesn't want to allow.

Comment: You're right. However, a Getter would allow the same. If such a constraint is a deal breaker, then friend does seem to be the only way to achieve this (apart from a nested class) - move the act of granting permission to specific users to compile time.

Comment: I know that a getter would allow the same, that's exactly what I said in the comments above (and note that the OP says he doesn't want a getter for this reason). By the way, the fact that it's a `const` method doesn't really help: The user can indirectly change the Window instance's state by operations on the HWND. e.g. calling `DestroyWindow(hwnd)` will make the `Window` instance's internal state invalid.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I suggest to provide a getter for the `HWND` because you will probably be needing that more often. Providing the getter does not mean that you take the responsibility of your Window class, it is still responsible for the window's life cycle. You just make it more usable and easier to divide your code in use cases.

That said, here is a more generic approach that you could try:

```
class Window;

class Direct3D {
public:
    void apply(Window &window, HWND hWnd);
};

class Window {
public:
    void accept(Direct3D &direct3d) {
        direct3d.apply(*this, this->m_hWnd);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use the friend keyword you can make sure window has no knowledge of the class that needs the hwnd.  Just make classes (that window and DirectX inherit from) that handle the actions for you.  This allows you to solve the problem for DirectX, AND for the next time it comes around.

Side Rant: 
Friend is not a four-letter word.  Friend, if used reasonably, is actually a great way to add gradation to C++'s access control (public, friend (when in protected), protected, friend (when in private) , private).

```
#include <iostream>

class HwndOwner;
class HwndWanter
{
protected:
    HwndWanter(){}
    int getHwndFromOwner(HwndOwner & owner);
};

class HwndOwner
{
protected:
    HwndOwner() : hwnd(42){}

private:
    friend class HwndWanter;
    int getHwnd()
    {
        return hwnd;
    }

    int hwnd;
};

class Window : public HwndOwner
{
    //This is not the class you are looking for...
};


class Direct3D : private HwndWanter
{
public:
    Direct3D(HwndOwner & owner)
        : HwndWanter()
    {

        std::cout << getHwndFromOwner(owner) << std::endl;
    }
};

int HwndWanter::getHwndFromOwner(HwndOwner & owner)
{
    return owner.getHwnd();
}

int main()
{
    Window window;
    Direct3D hwndWanter(window);
}
```

Output:

```
42
```